# How to convert a binary 64 digit string to a uint64_t in c++?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to initialize bitboards from an array of a chess board. Running a for loop through and checking if a piece matches, then appending the particular board with a 64 digit string converted to binary matching the pieces position.

```
for (int i=0;i<64;i++) {
    Binary="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
    Binary[i] = '1';
    if(chessBoard[i/8][i%8] == "P"){
        WP+=convertStringToBitboard(Binary);

    }
```

For my convertStringToBitboard function i've tried:

```
uint64_t convertStringToBitboard(std::string Binary){
    char * ptr;
    long long temp = std::stoull(Binary, &ptr, 2);
    std::cout << temp << std::endl;
    return temp;
}
```

as well as

```
uint64_t convertStringToBitboard(std::string Binary){
    std::bitset<64> x(std::string(Binary));
    return x;
}
```

Any help would be more than appreciated!

Comment: `bitset` and `to_ullong()` worked fine for me. Perhaps if you posted a more complete example of what didn't work we could try to help more.

Comment: Your question is not clear, please read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: What would you like me to post? More of the code? For both those examples I gave above they both wouldn't compile

Comment: Of course you can't just return a bitset as a uint64_t, you need to use the to_ullong function... If your code has errors, post the error messages. Post a complete example with your includes and a main that calls your functions with your data,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all instead of using strings you can use a simple shift

```
long long unsigned bin = 1LL << i;
```

Other than that there is no standard functions to convert binaries. You can invent one by looping through the string elements and shifting. something like the following:

```
long long unsigned bin = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
  long long unsigned bit = binaryString[i] - '0';
  bin |= (bit << i);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! Would that shift move a 1 left by i number of digits?

Comment: Can I shift the same number multiple times or will it alter the positions of the other 1's along the number?

Comment: it will shift all bits in the word left, so if you had 0101 (5) after shift 1 position left you will have 1010 (dec 10 or hex A). Shift left by '1' is equivalent to multiplying by '2'.

Comment: You can check language rule for binary arithmetic, which includes shifts left and right as well as bit-wise operators '&', '|', '^' and '~'. You might nee those to work with binary values.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`strtoull`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtoull/), like this:

```
std::string s = "747";
int64_t n = std::strtoull(s.c_str(), NULL, 0);
```

Comment: It compiles okay, but it causes a segmentation fault when it tries to pass the line. Here's the code: ` uint64_t temp = std::stoull(Binary.c_str(), NULL, 0); `

Comment: @MaxC - You don't show how you declared `Binary`, you sure it's `std::string`, or  is it a ptr to a `char*`?  Try it without the `.c_str()`.

Comment: It's a std::string, both ways seem to cause segmentation faults